# Fill data to class

Tags: c#, xml, class

I have a c# class, I am creating object to put data in class , some data i have no able to do, here is my code

```
InvoiceType oInvoiceType = new InvoiceType();  // my main object

// using object UBLVersionIDType
UBLVersionIDType oUBLVersionIDType = new UBLVersionIDType();
IdentifierType oIdentifierType = new IdentifierType();
oIdentifierType.Value = "UBL 2.1";
//oUBLVersionIDType.schemeID = oIdentifierType.schemeID;
oUBLVersionIDType.Value = oIdentifierType.Value;

// using object InvoiceTypeCodeType
InvoiceTypeCodeType oInvoiceTypeCode = new InvoiceTypeCodeType();
CodeType oCodeType = new CodeType();
oCodeType.Value = "01";
oInvoiceTypeCode.Value = oCodeType.Value;

// using Note
NoteType oNoteType = new NoteType();
oNoteType.Value = new 
TextType oTextType = new TextType();   // this show error
oTextType.Value = "This is a Note 1";   // this show error
oNoteType.Value = oTextType.Value;   // this show error

// asign main object
oInvoiceType.UBLVersionID = oUBLVersionIDType;
oInvoiceType.InvoiceTypeCode = oInvoiceTypeCode;
//oInvoiceType.Note = oNoteType;   // this show error !!!!!!!!
```

Next you can see the class

```
public partial class InvoiceType
{
    private UBLVersionIDType uBLVersionIDField;
    private InvoiceTypeCodeType invoiceTypeCodeField;
    private UBLExtensionType[] uBLExtensionsField;
    private NoteType[] noteField;

    public UBLVersionIDType UBLVersionID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uBLVersionIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uBLVersionIDField = value;
        }
    }
    public InvoiceTypeCodeType InvoiceTypeCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.invoiceTypeCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.invoiceTypeCodeField = value;
        }
    }
    public UBLExtensionType[] UBLExtensions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.uBLExtensionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.uBLExtensionsField = value;
        }
    }

    public NoteType[] Note
    {
        get
        {
            return this.noteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.noteField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class NoteType : TextType1
{
}
public partial class TextType1 : TextType
{
}

public partial class TextType
{

    private string languageIDField;

    private string languageLocaleIDField;

    private string valueField;


    public string languageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.languageIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.languageIDField = value;
        }
    }


    public string languageLocaleID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.languageLocaleIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.languageLocaleIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class UBLExtensionType
{

    private IDType idField;

    private NameType1 nameField;

    private System.Xml.XmlElement extensionContentField;

    public IDType ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    public NameType1 Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    public System.Xml.XmlElement ExtensionContent
    {
        get
        {
            return this.extensionContentField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.extensionContentField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The class "Invoice" has 4 fields to set data

```
private UBLVersionIDType uBLVersionIDField;
private InvoiceTypeCodeType invoiceTypeCodeField;
private UBLExtensionType[] uBLExtensionsField;
private NoteType[] noteField;
```

As you can see in the code, I set data to "uBLVersionID" and "InvoiceTypeCode", but I have not been able to assign data to notefield, and I don't know to set "uBLExtensionfield".

Does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved myself, This is the REAL answer and its working fine

```
NoteType[] arrayNote = new NoteType[3];
            NoteType oObj1 = new NoteType();
            TextType oTextType = new TextType();   
            oTextType.Value = "This is Note 1";   
            oObj1.Value = oTextType.Value;
            arrayNote[0] = oObj1;
            oObj1.Value = "This is Note 2";
            arrayNote[1] = oObj1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Code below compiles with no errors. I added missing classes.  The line with the ******* is causing issues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InvoiceType oInvoiceType = new InvoiceType();  // my main object

            // using object UBLVersionIDType
            UBLVersionIDType oUBLVersionIDType = new UBLVersionIDType();
            IdentifierType oIdentifierType = new IdentifierType();
            oIdentifierType.Value = "UBL 2.1";
            //oUBLVersionIDType.schemeID = oIdentifierType.schemeID;
            oUBLVersionIDType.Value = oIdentifierType.Value;

            // using object InvoiceTypeCodeType
            InvoiceTypeCodeType oInvoiceTypeCode = new InvoiceTypeCodeType();
            CodeType oCodeType = new CodeType();
            oCodeType.Value = "01";
            oInvoiceTypeCode.Value = oCodeType.Value;

            // using Note
            NoteType oNoteType = new NoteType();
            //oNoteType.Value = new ******************************************** bad
            TextType oTextType = new TextType();   // this show error
            oTextType.Value = "This is a Note 1";   // this show error
            oNoteType.Value = oTextType.Value;   // this show error

            // asign main object
            oInvoiceType.UBLVersionID = oUBLVersionIDType;
            oInvoiceType.InvoiceTypeCode = oInvoiceTypeCode;
            //oInvoiceType.Note = oNoteType;   // this show error !!!!!!!!
        }
    }

    public class CodeType
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class IdentifierType
    {
        public string Value { get;set;}
    }
    public class UBLVersionIDType
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public class InvoiceTypeCodeType
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class InvoiceType
    {
        private UBLVersionIDType uBLVersionIDField;
        private InvoiceTypeCodeType invoiceTypeCodeField;
        private UBLExtensionType[] uBLExtensionsField;
        private NoteType[] noteField;

        public UBLVersionIDType UBLVersionID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uBLVersionIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uBLVersionIDField = value;
            }
        }
        public InvoiceTypeCodeType InvoiceTypeCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.invoiceTypeCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.invoiceTypeCodeField = value;
            }
        }
        public UBLExtensionType[] UBLExtensions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.uBLExtensionsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.uBLExtensionsField = value;
            }
        }

        public NoteType[] Note
        {
            get
            {
                return this.noteField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.noteField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class NoteType : TextType1
    {
    }
    public partial class TextType1 : TextType
    {
    }

    public partial class TextType
    {

        private string languageIDField;

        private string languageLocaleIDField;

        private string valueField;


        public string languageID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.languageIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.languageIDField = value;
            }
        }


        public string languageLocaleID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.languageLocaleIDField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.languageLocaleIDField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class IDType
    {
    }
    public class NameType1
    {
    }
    public partial class UBLExtensionType
    {

        private IDType idField;

        private NameType1 nameField;

        private System.Xml.XmlElement extensionContentField;

        public IDType ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        public NameType1 Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }

        public System.Xml.XmlElement ExtensionContent
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionContentField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionContentField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , but still not working, classes you added, I have them , ... the issue is How to assign Notes . Ej, "this is a not 1", "this is a note 2"  to object Invoice.

Comment: Did you see the line that I marked bad with asterisks?

Comment: Of course, I left that line unfinished in the code that I posted above, that is one of the problems that I have not been able to solve and that is why I am asking for help, I would appreciate your suggestion ...

Comment: You are getting the errors because you left the line unfinished.  My code doe not have any compiler errors.